# Prevent images reloading when changing route in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a small gallery app where in the main view I have a bunch of images in *ngFor, and in the detail view, some more in a slider.

When I go back from detail to main view, all 66 images of main view are fetched again from the server.

How could I avoid that?

Here's my main view:

```
<div *ngFor="let exhibitor of exhibitors">
    <a [routerLink]="['/exhibitor', exhibitor.slug]">
      <div class="card" [ngClass]="{'dark':darky.mode}">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img [src]="'/assets/img/'+ exhibitor.artworks[0].img" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the go back button in the detail view:

```
<div class="goback" [routerLink]="['/']">
    <fa-icon [icon]="faAngleLeft"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

I changed my initial code to use `routerLink` and `[src]`, but still no joy.

Any tips?

Comment: Why are they not being retrieved from the browser cache would be my question here.?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy

Comment: https://itnext.io/cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-3e4c8b174d5f